# Emacs 24.1 & haskell-mode keybindings

Tags: haskell, emacs

I read at the [Haskell Emacs](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs/Keybindings_and_simple_usage) page that there are a number of keybindings available in haskell-mode. I downloaded Emacs 24.1 and loaded a Haskell file but the bindings do not work. For example, `C-c C-=` is supposed to insert an `=` and line up type signatures, but Emacs gives me a `C-c C-= is undefined`.

How do I enable these keybindings?

Comment: Are you in Haskell mode? (just double checking. :) )

Comment: Yup. It says "Haskell Ind WS Doc" at the bototm.

Comment: Interesting. They don't work for me either, emacs-bzr with emacs prelude on Arch Linux. `C-h m` makes no mention of those keybindings either, and I can't find them in `haskell-mode.el`...maybe they were removed some time ago?

Comment: on my QWERTZ-keyboard - DE layout - I cant enter C-c C-=  probably since = is done with shift pressed down. I can enter C-c = but this is not the same. I'll come back when I have found a solution.

Comment: You just need to press shift too..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your Emacs configuration:

```
(require 'haskell-indent)
```

Run `M-x haskell-indent-mode` in whatever buffer you're editing.
Then `C-c C-=` works for me.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. It's funny that Haskell indentation already worked for me but if I require haskell-indent the additional keybindings also work.

Comment: Emacs 24.3.1 from debian testing and this still doesn't work wven with the above hack - haskell-mode installed from the package manager.